# esc in readline() in R with message()

Tags: r, readline

**Problem:** I am writing a main function that nests other sub-routine functions, which use `readline()` to capture user input in R. When using the main function, a person may want to stop use of the function during the `readline()` part of a sub-routine function using the 'esc' key. Pressing the 'esc' key completely throws the user out of the function and all of the objects in the environment along with it but **only** when there is `message()` or `cat()` in the main function.

**Things I've tried:**

1. I noticed that `readline()` will still store an empty character string (`""`) despite completely exiting the function (i.e., pressing the 'esc' key when `Type:` appears in the following code:

```
> ans <- readline("Type: ")
Type:

> ans
[1] ""
```

2. When `readline()` is wrapped in a function, then I can achieve this same behavior and return an output (again, pressing 'esc' when `Type:` appears):

```
fun <- function()
{
  ans <- readline("Type: ")

  if(ans == "")
  {
    return("STOP")
  }else{
    return(ans)
  }
}

> ans <- fun()
Type: 

> ans
[1] "STOP"
```

3. When this function is a sub-routine for another function (e.g., the main function), an object the output of the sub-routine can be used to return a list of results (press 'esc' when `Type:` appears):

```
alt.fun <- function()
{
  object <- fun()

  if(is.character(object))
  {
    res <- list()
    res$one <- "one"
    res$two <- "two"
    res$three <- "three"

    return(res)

  }else{
    print("Continue to do other things")
  }
}

> result <- alt.fun()
Type: 

> result
$one
[1] "one"

$two
[1] "two"

$three
[1] "three"
```

4. When inserting a message to the user, however, the function returns nothing (press 'esc' when `Type:` appears):

```
main.fun <- function()
{
  object <- fun()

  if(is.character(object))
  {
    message("User stopped. Results up to this point have been saved.")

    res <- list()
    res$one <- "one"
    res$two <- "two"
    res$three <- "three"

    return(res)

  }else{
    print("Continue to do other things")
  }
}

> result_two <- main.fun()
Type: 

> result_two
Error: object 'result_two' not found
```

**Solution I'd prefer:** Ultimately, I'd like the solution of #4 in the things I've tried. More specifically, I would like a message to print to the user to let them know that they've stopped the function and that their results are saved. And then I would like their results to actually be saved and returned to the them.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I've come up with is to notify the user that when they press 'esc' their results will be saved:

```
fun <- function()
{
  message("Press 'esc' to stop (results will be saved).")

  ans <- readline("Type: ")

  if(ans == "")
  {
    return("STOP")
  }else{
    return(ans)
  }
}

main.fun <- function()
{
  object <- fun()

  if(is.character(object))
  {
    res <- list()
    res$one <- "one"
    res$two <- "two"
    res$three <- "three"

    return(res)

  }else{
    print("Continue to do other things")
  }
}

> result_two <- main.fun()
Press 'esc' to stop (results will be saved).
Type: 

> result_two
$one
[1] "one"

$two
[1] "two"

$three
[1] "three"
```

For my purpose, it's not optimal because the message is printed every time the `readline()` function appears.